# Draw Video onto canvas with original quality

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have a video (mp4) that I played using HTML5Video and display it onto canvas
The video's measurement is big (800x600), the video has a lot of texts in it,
the data rate and total bitrate are 127kbps and total duration is 20seconds
and the size is 324KB, and my technique is the same as in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage_video)

As you can see, they look ALMOST the same, but if I change the video to the one that I have(mentioned above), the one that redrawn in canvas will be very bad you can't read the text and the one in the video tag is totally as good as the original that you can read the text

Additional Information:
I redrew the video onto a 1360 x 768 canvas

any solution?

Comment: Do you define the 1360x768 resolution of the destination canvas with CSS styling or with the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<canvas>` tag?

Comment: @Philipp apparently, your comment was the solution, I was measuring the width and height using css, I should have used the width and height of the canvas

Answer (score 0):

The solution apparently was when we draw a canvas, you should the width&height from the canvas itself, credit to Phillip